# What is the proper way to map a Multi-column usertype inside a fluent NHibernate SubclassMap?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, usertype

For a project I'm working on I'm using a custom type to deal with IP Addresses in the database as a binary and address family pair.

If I attempt to map to my custom type in a SubclassMap it fails with a Mapping exception during startup

> NHibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of
>   columns: AddressAsset.Address type: IPAddressBinaryUserType

The failed mapping code is as follows:

```
public class AbstractAssetMap : ClassMap<AbstractAsset>
{        
    public AbstractFirewallAssetMap()
    {
        Table("asset");
        Id(x => x.FirewallAssetSk).Column("asset_sk").GeneratedBy.Native();
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn<string>("type");
        // ... other property mappings

    }
}

public class AddressAssetMap : SubclassMap<AddressAsset>
{
    public AddressAssetMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue(AbstractFirewallAsset.FirewallAssetType.Address);
        Map(x => x.Address)
            .CustomType<IPAddressBinaryUserType>()
            .Columns.Add("address_family", "address");
    }
}

// ... other SubclassMaps of AbstractAsset subclasses
```

If I remove one of the columns a MappingException is no longer thrown. This however is not a solution as I need the data from both columns.

Likewise, if I remove the subclassing and explicitly map the sub class using the same custom type it appears to work, and does not fail during mapping.
eg:

```
public class AddressAssetMap : ClassMap<AddressAsset>
{        
    public AddressAssetMap()
    {
        Table("asset");
        Id(x => x.FirewallAssetSk).Column("asset_sk").GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.Address)
            .CustomType<IPAddressBinaryUserType>()
            .Columns.Add("address_family", "address");
        // ... other property mappings

    }
}
```

What is the proper way to map a Multi-column usertype inside a fluent NHibernate SubclassMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try upgrading fluent nhibernate. Please take a look at known issue https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/issues/210